# How can i implement forget password link in my project?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, reset-password

I have an existing project in asp.net core 2.1 mvc. In the login page, I added forget password link and I wanna make like this thing; When user click this link, other page appear then user entered own email adress and click send buton then password reset link gonna user's email when user click password reset link user entered new password and confirm new password. How can i do this. There are so many resource but generaly in .net core identity but I dont use identity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session to reset the password.

[image]

The bakend

```
public IActionResult ForgetPassword()
    {
        //email: send a random code and save it in a session
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("randomcode",new Random().Next(1000,10000).ToString());
        
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ForgetPassword(string password,string randomCode)
    {
        //if the Vertification Code is not equals to the randomcode, return fail
        if (randomCode != HttpContext.Session.GetString("randomcode"))
        {
            return View();
        }
        //update database

        return View("index");
    }
```

Give the new password in this form.

```
<form action="/home/ForgetPassword" method="post">
  Password :<input type="text" name="password" value="" />
  Confirm Password :<input type="text" name="confirm_password" value=""  />
  Vertification Code: <input type="text" name="randomCode" value="" />
                  <input type="submit" name="reset" value="reset" 
   onclick="Confirm(event)"/>
</form>
```

javascript

```
<script>
 function Confirm(e) {
    var passw = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value
    var confirmPassw = document.getElementsByName('confirm_password')[0].value
    if (passw != confirmPassw)
        e.preventDefault()
 }
</script>
```